# Android Things Console bootanimation.zip

Tags: android, zip

I'm developing a new application in Android Things and when I want to do a new image in Android Things Console I have the next problem.

In the process of creating a new "build" into a model I have problems in the step 4 (Add additional build resources).

I want to upload a new animation to my image with the format bootanimation.zip but I can't. At first, it appears as if it is uploading but finally it disappears. When it happens, the computer shows the next message "Upload complete" but it's not true. The file ist'n loaded.

Does anyone have this problem? What could be happening?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Yes I'm seeing this problem too. The boot animation stuff was functional as recent as 6/17/2019.

Q2: It's not throwing errors on client side for me so this is probably due to some change on server-side. We need to open a request with Google support.

Work around #1:
The following is Mac specific but you can model a similar scenario on a PC.

Create your build image on Things Console as you would normally and then download it to your PC. Burn the image to micro SD using ApplePi-Baker or a similar app as if you're going to use the build with no boot animation.

The micro sd you made for Raspberry Pi is formatted with the EXT4 file system which is native to Ubuntu Linux. You can mount the sd card on a Mac using EXTfs (inexpensive add on app that gives Mac's access to EXT file systems) or on an Ubuntu machine. If you're on Windows you will need drivers/app to access EXT file systems or you could run Ubuntu on a VM etc. If you're customizing your config.txt for Android Things then you're already doing something similar.

Once you mount the sd card, one of the mount points on Mac will be "/oem". Create the folder "/oem/media/" if it does not already exist. Place your bootanimation.zip in /oem/media/.

Unmount the sd card and use... your animation should play like normal when Things boots.

Work around #2:
If you have a prior build image on Things Console with a boot animation that you want to continue to use, then you can create a new build image by selecting "Create from existing build" instead of "Start from scratch". Be sure not to delete old binaries from App Library for the existing build you are basing new builds from when using this work around.